# How to make opacity in image work in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi I have an image with 25% opacity and use it as image in sprite renderer

[image]

But opacity doesn't work. Below is the display sample and settings

[image]
[image]
[image]

Update:

I also change the sprite renderer color alpha but still doesn't work

[image]

Comment: Why not just edit the `Color` and set the alpha to `0.25` there?

Comment: @derHugo do you mean on the sprite renderer color between sprite and flip settings? I  already did that but it's not working

Comment: just to narrow it down .. does it work with built-in sprites (e.g. the UISprite for instance)? If so we at least know it has to be your image ^^ can you share it somehow? The one in the question is a JPEG without transparency ..

Comment: @derHugo I tried the built-in sprites but it's still not working

Comment: I downloaded this image And It works Fine

Comment: @YashVakil did you use it in sprite renderer?

Answer (score 0):

I've solve this problem by creating a URP/unlit material and adjust its alpha cause I'm using URP. You can also create your standard material and adjust its alpha

Answer (score -1):

Color(R,G,B,A). A is the alpha.

So:
SpriteRenderer.color = new Color(1f,1f,1f,1f) is a normal sprite
SpriteRenderer.color = new Color(1f,1f,1f,.5f) is about 50% transparent
SpriteRenderer.color = new Color(1f,1f,1f,0f) is about 100% transparent (Cant be seen at all, but still active)

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: How is this different to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75382767/7111561) and my comment on the question and OP stating this was already tried and didn't work?

Comment: this doesn't work in sprite renderer